# Spring: Resolve view names to .jsp files in /WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I have many .jsp files in /WEB-INF/views/*.jsp that I'd like to resolve like this:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/doggystyle/ -> /WEB-INF/views/doggystyle.jsp
```

How do I do this without specifying each resource in my @Controller?

Comment: doggystyle.jsp..what does the app do? :D

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 3):

Could you try using a UrlBasedViewResolver?

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

I am a bit confused because you mention @Controller and JSPs are for views not controllers. Hopefully this is what you're needing.

Comment: A view is provided data by a controller in the traditional MVC pattern, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

This is enough. Your call to GET http://localhost:8080/myapp/doggystyle will be internall processed as
GET http://localhost:8080/myapp//WEB-INF/views/doggystyle.jsp

If you are are using a Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
   @RequestMapping(value = "/doggystyle", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String getForm(Model model){
      return("doggystyle");
   }
}
```

That should do.
That should do. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can read that article regarding viewresolver

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html

13.5.1. Resolving views - the ViewResolver interface